# Login to different user via Touch ID from Lock screen

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, touch-id

1. I'm **user1**; close the laptop
2. After a minute or so, **user2** opens the laptop
3. Laptop shows Lock Screen for **user1**
4. **user2** now needs to click "Switch User" and only after that put his finger on Touch ID to open his account

Is it possible to make it so **user2** will not need to click "Switch User" and just put his finger to Touch ID to log in?

Comment: No, it’s not possible unless you are not logged in at the same time. I’m not sure but this might help you https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mchlp2439/mac you can look at “Switch accounts using Touch ID”